# CefSharp - Everything freezes when interacting with webView container

Tags: .net, winforms, vb.net-2010, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a winform application with a webView that seems to working normally... until I load this one particular page. After the document is finished loading, any attempt to interact with the container or right click in the content causes everything to freeze up. I can, however, interact with the content, click combo boxes etc. I can ctrl + alt + delete (Print Screen seems to work too) and it frees up the ui until I try to interact with the form again, except the red [X] in the corner, I can close the form after everything is freed up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use the winforms browser control for this project. It appears that the version of CEF (1) currently being used by CefSharp has issues with the javascript being used in the web application. CEF 3 does not appear to have those problems but CefSharp does not currently support CEF 3.